# 3 guys play frisbee

Tags: logical-deduction

**Story:**

> Three guys A, B and C meet daily to play frisbee. They determined: Always if A doesn't have a frisbee, then B has one. If B doesn't take along a frisbee, then C has one.
>
> Today B hasn't a frisbee.

**Question:**

> Which boys have a frisbee today?

Comment: Well, without even thinking, 'boys' is plural and B doesn't have a frisbee so A and C do.

Comment: How is this a puzzle? It’s a direct statement of a textbook style problem with an entirely mechanical solution. We generally don’t allow those. See [Are math-textbook-style problems on topic?](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2783/are-math-textbook-style-problems-on-topic) for more info.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a puzzle, nor is it related to puzzle-solving.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution:

> A and C have frisbees

Because:

> If A would't has a frisbee then B would has one. And when B has no frisbee, then C has one

Answer (score 1):

> A and C have frisbees.

This follows from the 2nd statement and the contrapositive of the 1st statement. Specifically:

1. > "*if A doesn't have a frisbee, then B has one.*" Therefore, if B **doesn't** have a frisbee, then A **does**.
2. > "*If B doesn't take along a frisbee, then C has one.*" Therefore, since B **doesn't** have one, C also **does**.